# jQuery Preserving order when parsing an array in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a Json array as mention below

```
var data=  "  [{"-1":0,"0":0,"1":0,"2":1,"3":0,"4":0,"5":1,"Total":2},{"-1":0,"0":0,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0,"Total":0},{"-1":0,"0":0,"1":0,"2":1,"3":0,"4":0,"5":1,"Total":2},{"-1":0,"0":0,"1":0,"2":1,"3":0,"4":0,"5":1,"Total":2}]";
```

When I do

```
JSON.Parse(data);
```

the order is original order is missing, it shows as below

```
0: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, -1: 0, Total: 2}
1: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, -1: 0, Total: 0}
2: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, -1: 0, Total: 2}
3: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, -1: 0, Total: 2}
```

Is there any way we can preserve the order of the parsed arry ?

Comment: What do you mean by `the order is original order is missing` ?

Comment: The array order is correct but objects have no guaranteed order of keys...especially when keys are numeric

Comment: You should avoid relying on key orders with javascripts objects. Either sort them or whatever, but **never** rely on key order.

Comment: Hi @Christheoreo, I mean the original key order,

Comment: _"Is there any way we can preserve the order of the parsed arry ?"_ The order of the parsed __array__ is still the same. The __objects__ in that array are rendered differently, because that just depends on how the browser decides to render objects. Properties in an object don't have an "order".

Comment: I still don't get what the issue is

Comment: why do you need to preserve the order of keys? your example have keys in order from -1 to 5 and accessing an element from an object is of complexity O(1) if you want to put them back in ascending order you convert them into array or Map`data.map(ele => Object.assign([], ele)`